# http-request testing of nodejs (connect) apps with mocha?

Tags: http, node.js, testing, connect, mocha.js

I want to write some integration-tests for my connect-middleware and test it with real-http-requests instead of mocked requests.

The middleware stack behaves differently depending on the configuration passed, that's why i wanted to run the middleware-server as a subprocess which i can restart with different configuration after each test.

The problem is that the test-server runs without problems (ether started directly or within test-file) and is accessible via browser, but i don't get a response via http.get(..) because the connection is refused.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

Here is my Setup...

```js
//MOCHA TEST FILE: testServer.test.js

function runTestServer(configEnv) {

    var cmd = "node " + path.resolve(__dirname, "runTestServer.js");

    var testSrv = exec(cmd, { "env" : configEnv },
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    });

    return testSrv;
}


describe("onRequest", function(){
    it("should return a response", function (done) {

        this.timeout(100000);

        var serverInstance = runTestServer({
            "appDir" : path.resolve(__dirname, "../../handleHttp/app")
        });

        http.get({host:'localhost', port:9090, path:'/'}, function (res) {
            //error thrown before this callback gets called
        });

    });
});
```

That's the content of my testServer.js file which runs as a subprocess.

```js
//Test-Process-File: runTestServer.js
var connect = require("connect"),
handleHttp = require("...")

var server = connect();
handleHttp.init(server); //this methods applies the middleware
console.log("TEST-SERVER listening on 9090");
server.listen(9090);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I figured this one out while posting the questions and want to answer it here, in case someone else is having the same kind of problem.***

### So what's the problem?

**The whole thing is async!**

So the server won't be initialized before the requests are being fired to the server.

### Solution

Give the subprocess some time to initialize and make the testServer-Loader Async!

```
function runTestServer(configEnv, callback) {

    var cmd = "node " + path.resolve(__dirname, "../runTestServer.js"),
    testSrv;

    testSrv = exec(cmd, { "env" : configEnv },
                 function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                   if (error !== null) {
                     console.log('exec error: ' + error);
                  }
              });

    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(testSrv);
    }, 1000);
}
```

My mocha-test-file:

```
describe("handleHttp", function() {
  describe("#Basic Requesting", function() {

    var serverInstance;

    before(function(done) {
        runTestServer({
            "appDir" : path.resolve(__dirname, "...")
        }, function(srvInstance) {
            serverInstance = srvInstance;
            done();
        });
    });

    //run your tests here
```

The fixed timeout is not really a nice solution. Maybe it's possible to enable some communication between the main and subprocess in order to find out when the http-server is ready. Suggestions appreciated.